# Geometric meaning of generating graded algebras in degree 1.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, group-actions, graded-rings

It is well known that gradings of a commutative ring correspond to actions of the multiplicative group on the corresponding affine variety.

Frequently one encounters the condition that with respect to a grading, the ring is generated by degree 1 homogeneous elements.

What does this condition mean in terms of the multiplicative group action?